# How many fixed points are there?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f:[0,10)\rightarrow [0,10]$ be a continuous mapping.Then

$(A)f$ need not have any fixed point.

$(B)f$ has atleast 10 fixed points.

$(C)f$ has atleast 9 fixed points.

$(D)f$ has atleast one fixed points.

**WHAT I THINK-** Since $[0,10)$ under usual metric is not  complete.So,by Banach fixed point theorem **$f$ need not have any fixed point** i.e.,(A) is true.

Please give your advice/suggestions/opinions about my choice.

If there is any other method by which we can deal with this problem,please share...

Comment: Just to say that Banach fixed point theorem isn't really relevant here because we don't know that $f$ is a contraction map.

Comment: @EdMo38:Gotcha!!

Comment: 10 mapping to 10 could be the fixed point but it doesnt exist in this mapping

Comment: @user29418:thanks for giving words to my thought...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take $f(x)=10$ for all $x\in [0,10)$. As we drop $10$, there are no fixed points. This counterexample immediately proves that statement $A$ is true.

**EDIT**: Suppose the question was whether a continuous map $f:[0,10]\rightarrow [0,10]$ has fixed points, how could we solve it?

If $f(0)=0$ or $f(10)=10$ there are fixed points, so assume this is not the case. Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Clearly $f(0)>0$ and $f(10)<0$. By the intermediate value theorem there must exist an $c\in (0,10)$ such that $g(c)=0$. Equivalently, $f(c)=c$.

So in this case you still don't need the machinery of Banach's fixed point theorem to solve the question.

Comment: :Can *Banach fixed point theorem* be applied here?

Comment: No, the metric space $[0,10)$ is not complete and we don't know whether $f$ is contracting. Also, as I gave a counterexample, it should be clear that the Banach fixed point theorem should fail here.

Comment: @PKStyles Banach fixed point theorem cannot be applied because its aplication (if applicable) would tell us that $f4 has a fixed point, which it does not have

Comment: I edited my answer to give an elegant solution to a related exercise. This also shows that you don't always need advanced machinery to solve problems.